# Creating a navbar with 3 items

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to create something like this:

[image]

A navigation bar with 3 items, is it possible to do this using `navigationBarItems`?

My current plan is to hide the navbar using:

```
.navigationBarTitle("")
.navigationBarHidden(true)
```

and then creating the 3 buttons using a `HStack`. The Problem I have is because I'm hiding the navbar, the click of one of the buttons take it to another view, which also then hides the navbar (Thats not what im looking for)

I have tried:

```
.navigationBarItems(trailing:
    HStack {
        Button("About") {
            print("About tapped!")
        }

        Button("Help") {
            print("Help tapped!")
        }
    }
)
```

But this creates the two items next to each other on the right side. I tried putting a `Spacer()` in the above `HStack`, but this doesn't work.

I would prefer to use `navigationBarItems` but can't seem to find a way to centre an item?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A navigation bar with 3 items, is it possible to do this using navigationBarItems?

No. Moreover `navigationBarItems` modifier is deprecated since SwiftUI 2.0

**SwiftUI 2.0**

This can be done with `toolbar` modifier as easy as attach it to any view inside `NavigationView`

Demo prepared & tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14:

[image: demo]

```
.toolbar {
    ToolbarItem(placement: .primaryAction) {
        Button(action: {}) { Image(systemName: "gear") }
    }
    ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
        Button(action: {}) { Image(systemName: "car") }
    }
    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigation) {
        Button(action: {}) { Image(systemName: "chevron.left") }
    }
```